# A class was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a class, it can no longer be used

Tags: flutter

The error says "A MyData was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a MyData, it can no longer be used.". I am not being able to find where is dispose method called.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

main.dart

```
void main() {
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
    if (kReleaseMode) exit(1);
  };
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
//////--------------------
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, MyData>(
          create: (_) => MyData('', 0),
          update: (ctx, auth, _) => MyData(
            auth.token,
            auth.user,
          ),
        ),
//////--------------------
        <other ChangeNotifierProvider s & ChangeNotifierProxyProvider s>
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData( all theme data ),
          home: auth.isAuth
              ? Home()
              : FutureBuilder(
                  future: auth.autoLogin(),
                  builder: (ctx, authResult) =>
                      authResult.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? Splash()
                          : Login()),
          routes: { <all the routes> },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_spinner == true) {
      Provider.of<MyData>(context, listen: false)
          .refreshData()
          .then((value) {
        if (value == true) {
          _chose =
              Provider.of<MyData>(context, listen: false).data.chose;
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _spinner = false;
          });
          return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (ctx) => AlertBox(),
          );
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        setState(() {
          _spinner = false;
        });
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertBox(),
        );
      });
```

myData.dart

```
Future<bool> refreshData() async {
    final String _url = 'url here';
    return await http
        .get(_url, headers: {'authorization': '$_auth'}).then((value) async {
   
      if (value.statusCode == 401) {
        Auth().logout();
      }

      if (value.statusCode == 200) {
        final _extractedData = jsonDecode(value.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        _data = MyData(data);
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      throw error;
    });
  }
```

error message (when error is not handled)

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: A MyData was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a MyData, it can no longer be used.
#0      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:117:9)
#1      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:123:6)
#2      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:217:12)
#3      MyData.refreshData (package:flutter_app_like4like/providers/myData.dart:210:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _HomeState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter_app_like4like/screens/home.dart:43:12)
#5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4786:12)
#6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
#7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
#8      Element.updateChild<…>
```

**I am not being able to locate dispose().**
**Any help will be useful**

Comment: You are subscribing on Provider on screen where you getting this error?

Comment: @fartem 
in myData.dart, if i remove notifyListeners(), I am not getting this error.

Comment: Can you add your code where you subscribed to the model?

Comment: I have edited the code. Sorry for the trouble. 

I am calling refreshData() (which is in myData.dart file) from home.dart. It is showing error at notifyListeners() (in myData.dart file)

Comment: Can you describe a situation when you causing this error?

Comment: on loading the app, home.dart is called. From here, I call a refreshData().

Comment: Can you add full code of your class and full error message to the question?

Comment: Have updated the code. Thank you for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the class that you're using gets disposed on the screen where it has been initialized. This usually happens to free the app from unused memory, i.e. when the app navigates from a screen to another. Similar to this issue, a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63862257) is to update the existing Object instead of initializing a new one.